# Comment terminer une lettre de sollicitation

Tags: politesse, correspondance

J'habite à Wervik, en Belgique, en Flandre, tout prêt de la frontière linguistique wallonne et de la frontière française.

Comme j'ai perdu mon travail, je suis à la recherche d'un nouvel emploi et je viens de trouver une opportunité intéressante à Moucron, dans la Wallonie.

J'aimerais bien y écrire (en envoyant un courriel), pour demander des renseignements, mais bien que je sache comment commencer une lettre pareille, je ne sais pas comment la terminer:

Début:

```
Cher,
```

Fin: (en ordre de politesse)

```
Formulation                   jugement personel
===========                   =================
'A plus' ou même 'A+'         fort trop informel
Salutations                   informel?
Bien a vous                   faisable?
Cordialement                  correcte?
Veuillez agréer l'expression  fort trop formel
de mes sentiments (les plus) 
distingués
```

Selon moi, la façon la plus apte est l'avant dernière (`Cordialement`), mais je n'en suis pas certain.

Y a-t-il quelqu'un qui sait:

- si l'ordre, comme je viens de l'écrire, est correct?
- si mon choix est correct?
- si mon choix était correct, si jamais je veux postuler en France (bien en sachant que l'utilisation de la langue française est plus formelle en France qu'en Belgique)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pour une demande de renseignements comme tu l'indiques, j'utiliserais la formulation `Cordialement`, je l'utilise egalement tous les jours dans les echanges avec mes clients.

Pour une lettre de motivation en revanche, je trouve que c'est plus formel donc j'utilise `Dans l’attente de votre réponse, je vous prie d’agréer, Madame, Monsieur, mes salutations distinguées`.